# NDSolve with InterpolatingFunction object

Tags: differential-equations

Imagine some functions like `x1[t]`, `y1[t]` given as `InterpolatingFunction` objects, for example as a result of solving an ODE with `NDSolve`.

Now I have an ODE for `x[t]`, `y[t]`, where (repeated) combinations like `x1[t]/Sqrt[(x[t] - x1[t])^2+(y[t] - y1[t])^2]` or `y1[t]/Sqrt[(x[t] - x1[t])^2+(y[t] - y1[t])^2]` appear.

This works fine, however it is inefficient, as for each call of `x1[t]` or `y1[t]` the `InterpolatingFunction` object is evaluated during the `NDSolve`. What would be much more efficient, is if one could for each time step evaluate `x1` and `y1` (i.e. each once) and plug in the result. I have not managed so far to make that efficient, as `NDSolve` does not accept a function of type `f[t_?NumericQ, ...]` when `t` is the independent time variable.

Any hints on how to speed up?

A minimum example how to show what is not working:

```
x1Rule = 
 NDSolve[{x1''[t] == -x1[t], x1[0] == 0, x1'[0] == 1}, 
   x1, {t, 0, 5}][[1]];
(* works fine *)

eqn[t_?NumericQ] := 
 Block[{x1func = 
    x1[t] /. x1Rule}, {x''[t] == -x[t] + 0.01*x1func + 0.02*x1func^2, 
   x[0] == 0.2, x'[0] == 0.5}
(* this function tries to be efficient in caching the value of x1[t] and re-use it twice *)

eqn2 = {x''[t] == -x[t] + 0.01*x1[t], x[0] == 0.2, x'[0] == 0.5} /. 
   x1Rule;
(* this is the same, but using the solution twice *)

NDSolve[eqn2, x, {t, 0, 3}]
(* works fine *)

NDSolve[eqn[t], x, {t, 0, 3}]
(* yields: NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of eqn[t] in the first argument eqn[t]. *)
```

Comment: Can you provide a working code to illustrate your problem?

Comment: `NDSolve` needs to process `eqn` symbolically before integrating it numerically, but `?NumericQ` prevents doing it.  So, replace `eqn[t_?NumericQ] ` by `eqn[t_] `.

Answer (score 1):

Make the right-hand side of the ODE a function of the variables:

```
ClearAll[rhs];
rhs[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  With[{x1func = x1[t] /. First@x1Rule},
   -x + 0.01*x1func + 0.02*x1func^2];

NDSolve[{x''[t] == rhs[x[t], t], x[0] == 0.2, x'[0] == 0.5}
 , x, {t, 0, 3}]
```

You could apply `First` to `x1Rule = First@NDSolve[...]` instead of inside `rhs` if you want to save a few microseconds per evaluation.

Side tip: You might use `InterpolationOrder -> All` in the `x1Rule` call. It ameliorates the weak singularities at each step of the `x1` solution, but it makes the interpolating function slightly longer to evaluate. It might speed things up overall by leading to fewer steps in the second ODE. Or it might not.

Comment: Thank you! That is bringing me closer. Unfortunately, my rhs is vector valued, and the Diff Eq. is set up like {{x''[t],y''[t]}==rhs[x[t],y[t],t], + iniital cond.}. This yields to an error: "There are more dependent variables, ... than equations, so the system is underdetermined", I think becuase NDSolve does not see that rhs yields two values? Calling rhs twice would be inelegant, and inefficient again ...

Comment: @StefanGillessen I think you're right. You can solve it as a vector-valued function `NDSolve[{xy''[t] == rhs[xy[t], t], xy[0] == {1, 0}, 
  xy'[0] == {0, 1}}, {xy}, {t, 0, 3}]`

Comment: Related: [(78641)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78641), [(110950)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110950)